# random words with random extension after Loaded in VS output window

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2022

When I hit F5 on my asp.net core application (Debug with IIS) and click on certain links to go to different pages I see these lines in the VS2022 output window:

```
'AspCoreDemo.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded '5y4zaoob.hun'. 
'AspCoreDemo.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'q511jkh3.tc3'. 
'AspCoreDemo.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'lehmiz0e.hht'. 
'AspCoreDemo.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'tzdojgzv.pf2'.
```

what is `'5y4zaoob.hun', 'q511jkh3.tc3'` etc. ?

Comment: are you using razor? i'm guessing they are just temporary assemblies

Comment: yes, Razor view engine, .cshtml views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words you see are related to the loading of modules into the CoreCLR runtime environment. These modules are binary files which contain compiled code and data that is needed to run your application.

Their names are randomly generated to identify each module. The goal is  avoiding naming conflicts between modules that are loaded into the runtime environment.